# Beautiful Soup table table parse

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, beautifulsoup

We are doing a college project where we want to extract data from a college timetable and use it in our own project.  We have a python script that extracts the data and it works great on the local machines, however when we try to use the same script on Amazon ec2 there is an error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# url from timetable.ucc.ie showing 3rd Year semester 1 timetable
url = 'http://timetable.ucc.ie/showtimetable2.asp?filter=%28None%29&identifier=BSCS3&days=1-5&periods=1-20&weeks=5-16&objectclass=programme%2Bof%2Bstudy&style=individual'

# Retrieve the web page at url and convert the data into a soup object
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

# Retrieve the table containing the timetable from the soup object for parsing
timetable_to_parse = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'grid-border-args'})

i = 0  # i is an index into pre_format_day
pre_format_day = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]  # holds un-formatted day information
day = [[],[],[],[],[],[]]  # hold formatted day information
day[0] = pre_format_day[0]

# look at each td within the table
for slot in timetable_to_parse.findAll('td'):
    # if slot content is a day of the week, move pointer to next day
    # indicated all td's relating to a day have been looked at
    if slot.get_text() in ( 'Mon', 'Tue' , 'Wed' , 'Thu' , 'Fri'):
        i += 1
    else:  # otherwise the td related to a time slot in a day
        try:
            if slot['colspan'] is "4":  #test if colspan of td is 4
                # if it is, append to list twice to represent 2 hours
                pre_format_day[i].append(slot.get_text().replace('\n',''))
                pre_format_day[i].append(slot.get_text().replace('\n',''))
        except:
            pass
        # if length of text of td is 1, > 11 or contains ":00"
        if len(slot.get_text()) == 1 or len(slot.get_text()) > 11 or ":00" in\
                slot.get_text():
            # add to pre_format_day
            pre_format_day[i].append(slot.get_text().replace('\n',''))

# go through each day in pre_format_day and insert formatted version in day[]
for i in range(1,6):
    j = 0
    while j < 20:
        if len(pre_format_day[i][j]) > 10:  # if there is an event store in day
            day[i].append(pre_format_day[i][j])
        else:  # insert space holder into slots with no events
            day[i].append('----- ')
        j += 2

# creates a string containing a html table for output
timetable = '<table><tr>'
timetable += '<th></th>'
for i in range(0, 10):
    timetable += '<th>' + day[0][i] + '</th> '

days = ['', 'Mon', 'Tue' , 'Wed' , 'Thu' , 'Fri']

for i in range(1,6):
    timetable += '</tr><tr><th>' + days[i] + '</th>'
    for j in range(0,10):
        if len(day[i][j]) > 10:
            timetable += '<td class="lecture">' + day[i][j] + '</td>'
        else:
            timetable += '<td></td>'

timetable += '</tr></table>'

# output timetable string
print timetable
```

The output on local machine is a table containing the data required.

The output on the the ec2 instance is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse2.py", line 21, in 
    for slot in timetable_to_parse.findAll('td'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Both machines are running Ubuntu 14.10, Python 2.7 but for some reason I can't figure out it seems not to be getting the required page from the url and extracting the table from that but after that im lost.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you examine the html data you got back when running on the ec2 instance? Is it serving a different page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that ec2 was using a different parser to local machine.
fixed with.

apt-get install python-lxml

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the EC2 instance and go through it line-by-line in the Python CLI until you find the problem. For some reason, BeautifulSoup parsing works slightly differently on different systems. I have had the same problem, and I don't know the reason behind it. It's hard for us to give you specific help you without knowing the contents of the HTML.

Comment: So I try print each variable, they print upto and including soup . If I print table_to_parse I get a none error, the output of soup is  http://cs1.ucc.ie/~jmt2/soup.txt